# count JSON multidimendional array in php

Tags: php, json

i got this json format form form-builder plugin, in hope someone could help out i need to count the number of times certain fields occur so i can create a database for them

```
[ { "cssClass" : "checkbox",
    "required" : "false",
    "title" : "hello save",
    "values" : { "2" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "save"
          },
        "3" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : " save 2"
          },
        "4" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "save 3"
          },
        "5" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "save 4"
          },
        "6" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "save 5 "
          },
        "7" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "Save 6"
          }
      }
  },
  { "cssClass" : "textarea",
    "required" : "false",
    "values" : "you did not say hello properly"
  },
  { "cssClass" : "checkbox",
    "required" : "false",
    "title" : "whats up save",
    "values" : { "2" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "i got your back"
          },
        "3" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "i  got your back 2"
          },
        "4" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "i got your back 3"
          },
        "5" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "1 got your back 4"
          },
        "6" : { "baseline" : "false",
            "value" : "i got your back 5"
          }
      }
  }
]
```

i want to be able to count the number of cssClass checkbox and the corresponding values value to help create a database table for insert in mysql or mongodb
i will like it in a format like this

```
count($data[cssclass])
count($data[cssClass][values])
```

i get

```
Notice: Undefined index: cssClass in C:\wamp\www\callme\repo\index.php on line 45
```

i will appreciate any solution in php or nodejs  sice am quite new to Json

!============================================================================!
Hello guys, thanks for your timely response, i appreciate and feel very privileged to have u guy but it didn't really solve the challenge maybe i was not clear enough so this is the program logic. for the given json data i will like to sort it in a way that i can get the tile of the checkbox and its values which to create database entries for the user e.g
for array with checkbox get title and number of values (value) so i can have something like  say
checkbox1  title values = 6
checkbox2  title values = 5

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Object in your example is an Array. You can either use the following code to count all of the values:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
    $total += count($row['values']);
}
```

or you can use the following to reach one object:

```
count($data[0]['values']);
```

Of course you'll need to use

```
json_decode($json_string,true)
```

to convert your json object into a PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

You never deal with "json objects" directly. JSON is just a text string that happens to represent a javascript-style data structure. You always deal with NATIVE data structures, so

```
$array = json_decode($your_json);
$count = count($array['cssclass']);
```

Is what you'd do in PHP - convert to a native PHP array/object, then do your counting on that.

And as for what you should be counting on, once you've decoded back to native PHP, you can examine the actual structure with

```
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Hello guys thanks for your response but it didnt really solve the challenge maybe i was not clear enough so this is the program logic.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there:

```
<?php

$json = '[{"cssClass":"checkbox","required":"false","title":"hello save","values":{"2":{"value":"save","baseline":"false"},"3":{"value":" save 2","baseline":"false"},"4":{"value":"save 3","baseline":"false"},"5":{"value":"save 4","baseline":"false"},"6":{"value":"save 5 ","baseline":"false"},"7":{"value":"Save 6","baseline":"false"}}},{"cssClass":"textarea","required":"false","values":"you did not say hello properly"},{"cssClass":"checkbox","required":"false","title":"whats up save","values":{"2":{"value":"i got your back","baseline":"false"},"3":{"value":"i got your back 2","baseline":"false"},"4":{"value":"i got your back 3","baseline":"false"},"5":{"value":"1 got your back 4","baseline":"false"},"6":{"value":"i got your back 5","baseline":"false"}}}]';
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$cssClasses = array_filter($obj, function($el){ return $el["cssClass"] == "checkbox" });

print_r($cssClasses);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with a loop you will get out what you want (but I am not 100% sure if I understand you correctly).

```
<?php 
$json   = '[ { "cssClass" : "checkbox", "required" : "false", "title" : "hello save", "values" : { "2" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "save" }, "3" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : " save 2" }, "4" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "save 3" }, "5" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "save 4" }, "6" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "save 5 " }, "7" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "Save 6" } } }, { "cssClass" : "textarea", "required" : "false", "values" : "you did not say hello properly" }, { "cssClass" : "checkbox", "required" : "false", "title" : "whats up save", "values" : { "2" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "i got your back" }, "3" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "i got your back 2" }, "4" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "i got your back 3" }, "5" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "1 got your back 4" }, "6" : { "baseline" : "false", "value" : "i got your back 5" } } } ]';

// first convert the json string to an array (as the others already said)
$array  = json_decode($json);   
$boxes  = array();              
foreach ($array as $obj) 
{
    if ($obj->cssClass == "checkbox")
    {
        $boxes[] = array(
            "title" => $obj->title,
            "count_values" => count( (array)$obj->values )  // cast the object as an array to count the indexes
        );
    }
}      
?>
```

This will give you a new array, containing only the checkboxes with titles and the number of values.

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => hello save
            [count_values] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => whats up save
            [count_values] => 5
        )

)
*/
```